# Copy of innodb /data dir not working

Tags: mysql, innodb, homebrew

I successfully installed fresh 5.6.27 mysql through homebrew.

Now I want to restore innodb databases from previous mysql install. I copied data/ dir from the old one to a new one. It contains `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile1`, `ib_logfile0` and all databases as directories with the tables `.frm` as well as `.ibd` files.

`my.cnf` are same in both installs.

However the new 5.6.27 is not loading databases after the restart.

Any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move a database from one server to another?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another)

Comment: anything relevant in the [error log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that this brew install did set up data dir at `/usr/local/var/mysql`.

`ps auxww|grep [m]ysqld` helped to reveal that.

So I just copied there, restarted and voila, dbs are there.